# How Will Joomla work with MariaDB?

Tags: joomla, mariadb

I am already have WAMP stack in my system and I am using Joomla based system. To test MariaDB before using, I installed MariaDB also in my system with Port number 3305. Now, when I try to install Joomla 2.5, there is only option to choose MySQL or MySQLi. Also, there is no option to choose port. Also, there is no such variable in configuration file to add port number and use MariaDB.I think, MariaDB is similar to MySQL so no additional driver required for it.

I am able to connect MariaDB through SQL client as well as from command prompt by just adding port number. So, How can I use MariaDB in Joomla application?

Comment: You lost me at WAMP. Kidding, but I dont feel that WAMP or XAMP are suitable even for testing software designed primarily for Linux servers. There is just too much stuff it cant do and too much other stuff that is hacky to achieve. Iv seen so many people struggle with something they think is an issue, and then install on Linux and realize the only issue was losedows.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you use the 5.x version. They should act the same as 'normal' mysql. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility/ to read more about the compatibility betweet MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: I have both MySQL5.5 as well as MariaDB5.5 version. But, how to distinct it? How Joomla will know to use MariaDB instead MySQL?

Comment: If i'm correct, MariaDB will replace MySQL, you couldn't have both running on the same server.

Comment: NO, It doesn't replace. Just need to change the Port and installation name.

Comment: Sounds like you can change that in the Joomla (database) configuration.

Comment: I ran with Mariadb for a long time. It's a drop in replacement. When you create the database make it in mariadb.
Also, always use mysqli, since php has deprecated mysql.

Comment: @ursitesion I cant imagine them running on the same server, MariaDB hijacks the MySQL socket for one, plus their dependency libs clash, you cant even install MariaDB without completely removing all MySQL libs.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla works with MariaDB seamlessly.

You need to make sure you have `pdo_mysql` available by installing the `php-mysql` module (may be called `php5-mysql` depending on your OS and repo).

If its installed properly MariaDB will show up under the **mysql** heading in `phpinfo()`;

The term "Drop in replacement for MySQL" is being thrown around a lot and MariaDB is far from that. Many things about it are not compatible with MySQL including one major whoopsie: -

MariaDB does not know the variable name `default-character-set` and if you try to set it in your `/etc/my.conf` like `default-character-set = utf8` the service will not start.

I havent found a way run MariaDB on a server running MySQL or visa versa (not that youd usually want to) since the supporting libs clash. So if you wanna replace one with the other you have to be sure to clean up all dependencies.

The name also makes me uneasy, placing all of my information in a database named Maria feels akin to passing my credit cards to my wives and daughters, just nerve wracking.

But, it does "Drop In" to Joomla just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Enter `localhost:3305` as hostname.